# css hover nested classes propagates

Tags: css, hover, nested, propagation

I know this is a classical one but I find no answer on the net:

I have this html code:

```
<div class="comment>
  <div class="myLinks">Some Links</div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="myLinks">Some Links</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I have this css (written in scss):

```
.myLinks {
  display: hidden;
}

.comment {
  &:hover {
    .myLinks {
      display: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

When the pointer goes above the first comment block, the nested one's hover effect is also activated. What I want is my links to be visible only in the comment being hovered, not in his parents or children.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `visibility` and not `display`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.myLinks{
  display:none;
}

.comment:hover > .myLinks {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used to this css

```
.myLinks{
display:none;
}

.comment:hover .myLinks{
display:block;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mNaVY/1/)***

**or**

### -------

```
.myLinks{
    visibility:hidden;
    }

    .comment:hover .myLinks{
    visibility: visible;
    }
```

***[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/mNaVY/2/)***

Comment: Thanks for your help but the goal was to display the links only in the hovered content, not to display the nested content.